# SQL Server, odbc newbie question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, connectivity, odbc

My new job has some sql server 2014.  I am an Oracle DBA.

I need to help a client.

They are having issues creating the ODBC connection from their laptop to the database server (or whatever MS calls a database)

I have access to MS SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

Questions:
How can I create an ODBC connection to this database on my laptop to test and provide a procedure for the client?

Do I need to create myself a user to test?

(In oracle I would install the client and give them a tnsnames and an alias to use and maybe use tnsping or sqlplus to check the connection)

EDIT1:

I use Oracle SQL Develper and it uses jdbc.  maybe you can help me setup my first JDBC connection.

EDIT2:
Tried the ODBC data source and it failed
[image]

EDIT3:
Checked if 1433 is enabled and looks like something is connecting to this server;

Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State

TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

TCP    xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3389   xxx.xx.xx.xxx:56010    ESTABLISHED

TCP    xxx.xx.xx.xxx:56984  xxx.xx.xx.xxx:2074     ESTABLISHED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both Max Vernon and Dan Guzman.They both helped me greatly. It was a firewall issue.

- Dan Guzman's powershell script let me test my changes.
- Max Vernon's odbc setup instructions let me get connected.

**Solution:**

I got admin rights to the server and followed [these steps](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2011/06/how-to-open-firewall-port-1433-for-sql-server-database-engine-for-use-with-scom-or-anything-else/) to open an inbound port:

1. I downloaded and installed the msodbcsql.msi to get the SQL Server odbc client for my laptop.
2. I created the ODBC datasource.
3. I downloaded jtds-1.3.1.jar
4. I followed Oracle's; "How To Create a Connection With SQL Server In SQL*DEVELOPER" (Doc ID 471882.1)
5. I was able to get Oracle's SQL Dev to talk to SQL Server and both the user and I have access to that database.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), you don't need to "create" a connection via ODBC, you can just connect directly to the server via the SSMS user interface:

[image]

In SQL Server, the equivalent of an Oracle "database server" is called a "SQL Server Instance".  It can contain many databases, which are similar to a "schema" in Oracle.

So, when you connect via SSMS, you connect to the instance, which takes the form of:

```
COMPUTERNAME
```

For a "default, unnamed" instance, or for a "named" instance:

```
COMPUTERNAME\INSTANCENAME
```

INSTANCENAME gets resolved to a port automatically by the SQL Server Browser Service; if that service is not running, or is blocked by a firewall, you may need to connect using the port number, as in:

```
tcp://COMPUTERNAME,0000
```

where `0000` is the port number for the instance.

If you don't have access to the instance, you'll see an "authentication failed" error message.  If SSMS cannot contact the instance because of a firewall, or the server is not listening on the port you specified, you'll see an error indicating that, similar to:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. "

To create a connection via ODBC, you open the ODBC Data Source Administrator from the Windows Control Panel.  You can either create a "User DSN" or a "System DSN", either way choose the `SQL Server Native Client 12.0` driver:

[image]

Fill in the details (use the servername as detailed above):

[image]

Accept the defaults for the rest of the configuration screens if you plan to use integrated Active Directory domain authentication.  If the login will be made using a SQL Server Login, enter those details on this screen:

[image]